# Query does not use index when selecting all records

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, t-sql

This is my first time handling a large database, and I was wondering why the two queries below are different in terms of execution plan.

I have setup an index on a specific table:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_UBHSD_xploc_trandt2] ON [dbo].[UBHSD]
(
    [xploc] ASC, [trandt2] ASC
)
WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, 
        DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) 
        ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

When I ran this query, it uses the index.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt 
FROM [dbo].[UBHSD] 
WHERE [xploc] != '' AND [trandt2] >= CAST('2012-01-01' AS DATETIME)
```

[image]

[Here's a larger one.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qo9n7mqukklrmi9/1.JPG)

But when I ran a query without using aggregate:

```
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[UBHSD] 
WHERE [xploc] != '' AND [trandt2] >= CAST('2008-01-01' AS DATETIME)
```

[image]

[Here's a larger one.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/39zdxqw1dqkmsd4/2.JPG)

I was expecting that both queries would use an index. But the second query performs a full table scan.

Why is this happening? Did I miss something?

Comment: You have `SELECT *` in the second, that's the crucial difference. You ask for columns in the result which are not included in the index.

Comment: @ypercube thanks for the comment. I though indexes work only for filtering mechanism. If that's the case, any columns that are needed should have an index? Sorry for this, I'm new with thing.

Answer (score 5):

You've used `SELECT *` which, presumably, has more columns than `xploc` and `trandt2`. So SQL Server can easily derive the count by traversing the index pages. It can't get the other columns that aren't in the index from there, so it has to go to the table.

Depending on how many columns are in the table (and a host of other factors), SQL Server can usually make one of two choices in a case like this:

1. Perform a seek (which looks like a range scan in your case), and then perform key/RID lookups to retrieve the other columns not covered by the index.
2. Suck it up and perform a scan.

In your case there are probably enough rows satisfied by the `WHERE` clause that it is actually more efficient to perform the scan.

Some ways to make this more efficient:

1. [Stop using `SELECT *` - just list the columns you need](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list).
2. Once you have whittled down to the actual columns you need, change the index to `INCLUDE` the other columns in the actual `SELECT` list you need.
3. You could consider making an index filtered by adding a `WHERE` clause, depending on whether this exact query is one that is run frequently (and if there is a lot of data pre-2012).

As an aside, why is there no clustered index on this table?

Comment: Thank you for the response sir. There is a clustered index and it's the primary key. However, how will I improve this query? All the columns are needed since I'm migrating from very old database into a new one. The old database was now hosted on sql server 2008. What possible things will I do so I can optimize the query more?

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO which no.1 do you mean, the first or the second. if that's the second, I need all columns since I'm migrating to a new database.

Comment: @FireExit #2.1 Why are you concerned with an index being used if you're migrating to a new database? Are you planning on doing a migration every 30 minutes?

Comment: @JW웃 are you and FireExit the same person?

Comment: @AaronBertrand No. It was my fault not to see Sir JW's account login, I am an on the job trainee on their company and he assigned this job to me and I have no idea about this since dabatase thing is very new to me. :)